# "most simple php preg code" to check the assistance of dot within the string

Tags: php, regex

what would be the "most simple php preg code" to check the assistance of dot anywhere within the string ?
i searched for similar topics but solutions are somewhat complicated.

in addition, what other simple code we can use instead of **preg** in such circumstances?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a boolean to see if a period exists, you could do:

```
if (strpos($string,'.')===FALSE) {
   // does not exist
} else {
   // exists
}
```

Comment: why the following code doesn't work as expected according to above code?  i want if the string '123456' exists anywhere within the password which users enter in registration form, my message be shown.    the code is :    if (strpos($value,'123456')===TRUE) {
                     $return = $register_msg['dont_use_weak_pass_msg'];
    }